# Access Form Go To Record

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access, listbox

In Access, I have a main form with a listbox.  The listbox is used to navigate to different records on the main form.   The main form also has a button with the following code to open a dialog form on which I add a new record.

```
Private Sub New_Btn_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm "New Issue", , , , acFormAdd, acDialog
    Requery

    Me.ID_Box.SetFocus
End Sub
```

After I close the dialog form, I want the listbox to update and to select the new record that added on the "New Issue" form AND I want the main form to navigate to the new record.

I cannot figure out how to make either of these actions occur.  Please help me find the best method for these steps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the listbox has a rowsource, you can requery the ListBox to show the new record like this:
`ListBox1.Requery`

Then to move the 'main' form to the latest record (assuming the ID/PK is an autonumber field, which is how the form recordsource is sorted):
`DoCmd.GoToRecord , "MainFormNameHere",acLast`

If you don't have an ordered recordset, you can use

```
  Me.Recordset.FindFirst "PrimaryKeyField = " & NewRecordPK
```

Where NewRecordPK is a variable with the new records primary key stored.

You could call this from the dialog if you like. Just make sure you save the record first using something like `Docmd.Save` Then,

```
Forms!frmMainForm.Form.Recordset.FindFirst "PrimaryKeyField = " & Me.PrimaryKeyField
```